# Execute multiple languages within bash shell script

Tags: bash, unix, webserver, centos7

I need to create a shell script that will execute **node**, **perl**, **php**, and **python** servers. How can I execute the various languages within bash?

Answer (score 3):

You just run the appropriate interpreter.

```
#!/bin/bash

python script1.py
perl script2.pl
# etc
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will try it out.

Comment: Or add the appropriate shebangs to the python and perl scripts (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python`), make them executable (`chmod +x /path/to/script1.py`), and then run them with either `/path/to/script1.py` or `./script1.py`. Note that the `./` version only works if it's in the script's current working directory (which is not generally the same as the directory the script is in).